# Show all posts under a custom taxonomy even if those posts belong to other categories as well

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type 'tribe_events' and custom taxonomy 'tribe_events_cat' and i want to get all posts under a specific category but the only problem here is I only get those posts which have only that category . for example if 1 post is attached to 2 categories then it will not show in the my requested category even though it has that category quick help would be appreciated and here is my code

```
    query_posts( 
                             array( 'post_type' => 'tribe_events', 
                             'posts_per_page' => -1,

                             'tax_query' => array(

                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => $cat,

                                ),
                            ),

                             ));
```

Comment: What is the value of `$cat`?

Comment: $cat will hold the category id

Answer (score 0):

```
    $terms = get_terms( array(
       'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
       'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $cat = array();

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $cat[] = $term->term_id;
    }

query_posts( 
  array( 'post_type' => 'tribe_events', 
   'posts_per_page' => -1,

   'tax_query' => array(

      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $cat,
     ),

));
```

Can you try this code? Hope it works

Comment: You want to get all posts of "tribe_events" post type which has "tribe_events_cat" taxonomy assigned right? or am I missing something?

Comment: `code`
$terms = get_terms( array(
       'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
       'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $cat = array();

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
       $cat[] = $term->term_id;
    }

query_posts( 
  array( 'post_type' => 'tribe_events', 
   'posts_per_page' => -1,

   'tax_query' => array(

      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $cat,
        'operator' => 'IN'
     ),

));

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking up all your time the problem was the date of events . Past events just filtered out of loop and thats why they wont show no matter what . Stupid me :|